# Use of Apache 2.0 Licensed K9 Email Android App in Commercial Email App

Tags: android, client-relations, email, apache-license

I want to improve usability of K9 Email client, Make a new UI and implement some additional functionality.
This software is Licensed Under Apache 2.0.
http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/
https://github.com/obra/k-9

Can I use the whole source code of this app with some modifications to some of classes and make this app a Commercial One?
I want some legal Advice.
If I succeed in this then I have wish to share revenue with original developer of this app.
Please give me some pointers on this.
I have read about Apache 2.0 license.
I am not clear about this line..
"provide clear attribution to The Apache Software Foundation for any distributions that include Apache software"
From Apache FAQ
http://www.apache.org/foundation/licence-FAQ.html
And Clause 4 D from this link
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Please Provide your Inputs on this..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Apache licensing mean by "Permitted: Commercial Use"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223004/what-does-the-apache-licensing-mean-by-permitted-commercial-use)

Answer (score 1):

Apache is a very loose and permissive license. All they want is for you to acknowledge that you used their code (giving them credit for their part), and for you to include their license.

You don't have to release the modified source. You don't have to give them money.